# Selenium ошибка атрибута

Tags: python, selenium

Не могу понять что не так...

```
followers_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span").get_property('title')
            followers_count = followers_button.text
            followers_count = int(followers_count.split(' ')[0])
            print(f"Количество подписчиков: {followers_count}")
            time.sleep(2)
```

Ошибка

```
  File "C:\python\Instabot\instabot1.py", line 121, in <module>
    mybot.get_all_followers()
  File "C:\python\Instabot\instabot1.py", line 77, in get_all_followers
    followers_count = followers_button.text
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: вы в тайтле ссылки, который является строкой, хотите найти текст... что не понятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Я новичок, поэтому немного не понимаю( в строке содержится текст, а конкретней количество подписчиков - цифра. Как мне извлечь эту информацию для дальнейшей операции...?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю что так:

```
followers_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span").get_property('title')
            followers_count = int(followers_count.split(' ')[0])
            print(f"Количество подписчиков: {followers_count}")
            time.sleep(2)
```

Либо вот так:

```
followers_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span")
            followers_count = followers_button.text
            followers_count = int(followers_count.split(' ')[0])
            print(f"Количество подписчиков: {followers_count}")
            time.sleep(2)
```

Все зависит от того какой элемент вы брали.